# Why is the range of hue 0-180° in opencv

Tags: opencv, hsv

Can anybody explain to me why the hue value of an HSV image in OpenCV only goes to 180° and not the full 360°?

I have found somewhere that OpenCV uses a 180° cylinder, but I can not really visualize such a cylinder.

Thanks in advance!
J

Answer (score 38):

try to put 360 into a uchar ;)

so, it's just divided by 2 to make it fit..

Comment: hmm ? what do you mean ? maybe it should be added, that it's only divided by 2 in the 8bit case ?

Comment: I didn't express my thought correctly. I meant you checked the same documentation as I did, but read two paragraphs more and found out the actual thing that explains the issue. My point was that the original question is a bit newbie and it took only a couple of seconds to post an answer.

Comment: They mean a uchar (i.e. uint8) can only encode numbers 0 to 255.  So to make a 0-360 value fit conveniently, the OpenCV people just decided "lets divide it by 2".

Comment: what about cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV vs  cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL ????

Answer (score 22):

The ranges that OpenCV manage for HSV format are the following:

For HSV, Hue range is [0,179], Saturation range is [0,255] and Value range is [0,255]. Different softwares use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges.

Here is the link to the OpenCV documentation that explains it.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html

Comment: what about cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV vs cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL ????

Answer (score 3):

According to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

For the 8-bit images, H is converted to H/2 to fit to the [0,255] range. So the range of hue in the HSV color space of OpenCV is [0,179]

Comment: what about cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV vs cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL ????

Answer (score 0):

Is it really so?I think for HSV the ranges are as H[0-179], S[0-255], V[0-255].Please see the link and help me understand if I am missing something. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

If you need to convert the range of Hue, see the link below.
http://en.literateprograms.org/RGB_to_HSV_color_space_conversion_%28C%29#

Comment: what about cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV vs cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL ????