# Trying to track green dot using OpenCV, cannot find color range

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, colors

I was wondering if anyone knew what color ranges I should use (HSV) to track this green dot easily.

I am currently using this (doesn't work):

```
# Define green color range
lower_green = np.array([60, 200, 100])
upper_green = np.array([65, 255, 255])
```

I am trying to track this green dot in the image: [Green Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFBIs.png)

Comment: Please (re)read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and show a bit more code, as well as a slightly more elaborate description of what you set out to do, what code you wrote (and why), what you're seeing that code (not) do, and what you already did in terms of debugging and (re)searching.

Comment: Expand your blue lower and upper values and lower your lower_green value. Increment them by +-10 at a time.  Use a color picker on your image to test value ranges.

Comment: I think you have your array values reversed.  You need to specify in BGR order for use in cv2.inRange().  RGB order values are approx rgb(63 201 131).  So you need to reverse your lower values as 100,200,60 and your upper values as 255,255,65.  But as I mentioned above, you should expand the B and G ranges more

Comment: Try `lo=[50, 50, 50]` and `hi=[70, 255,255]`

Comment: # define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255) in https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

Comment: tried with your image 0,87,0 /  255,255,255  see https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/master/bin/range-detector

Answer (score 1):

using     [imutils/bin/range-detector](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/master/bin/range-detector) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# USAGE: You need to specify a filter and "only one" image source
#
# (python) range-detector --filter RGB --image /path/to/image.png
# or
# (python) range-detector --filter HSV --webcam

import cv2
import argparse
from operator import xor


def callback(value):
    pass


def setup_trackbars(range_filter):
    cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars", 0)

    for i in ["MIN", "MAX"]:
        v = 0 if i == "MIN" else 255

        for j in range_filter:
            cv2.createTrackbar("%s_%s" % (j, i), "Trackbars", v, 255, callback)


def get_arguments():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-f', '--filter', required=True,
                    help='Range filter. RGB or HSV')
    ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=False,
                    help='Path to the image')
    ap.add_argument('-w', '--webcam', required=False,
                    help='Use webcam', action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-p', '--preview', required=False,
                    help='Show a preview of the image after applying the mask',
                    action='store_true')
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    if not xor(bool(args['image']), bool(args['webcam'])):
        ap.error("Please specify only one image source")

    if not args['filter'].upper() in ['RGB', 'HSV']:
        ap.error("Please speciy a correct filter.")

    return args


def get_trackbar_values(range_filter):
    values = []

    for i in ["MIN", "MAX"]:
        for j in range_filter:
            v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("%s_%s" % (j, i), "Trackbars")
            values.append(v)

    return values


def main():
    args = get_arguments()

    range_filter = args['filter'].upper()

    if args['image']:
        image = cv2.imread(args['image'])

        if range_filter == 'RGB':
            frame_to_thresh = image.copy()
        else:
            frame_to_thresh = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    else:
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    setup_trackbars(range_filter)

    while True:
        if args['webcam']:
            ret, image = camera.read()

            if not ret:
                break

            if range_filter == 'RGB':
                frame_to_thresh = image.copy()
            else:
                frame_to_thresh = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        v1_min, v2_min, v3_min, v1_max, v2_max, v3_max = get_trackbar_values(range_filter)

        thresh = cv2.inRange(frame_to_thresh, (v1_min, v2_min, v3_min), (v1_max, v2_max, v3_max))

        if args['preview']:
            preview = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=thresh)
            cv2.imshow("Preview", preview)
        else:
            cv2.imshow("Original", image)
            cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF is ord('q'):
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with your input :

[image]

got with  `python range-detector.py --filter HSV --image input.png` :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> if anyone knew what color ranges I should use (HSV) to track this
> green dot easily.

The problem can be fixed.

Snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# Create trackbars for color change
# Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
#[ Why is the range of hue 0-180° in opencv ][1]
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

# Set default value for Max HSV trackbars
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize HSV min/max values
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0

while(1):
    # Get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin', 'image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin', 'image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin', 'image')
    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image')

    # Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Convert to HSV format and color threshold
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if((phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display result image
    cv2.imshow('image', result)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea why imutils doesnt enforce h max 179 in his range detector , see below ??

Comment: I am talking abou hue value

Comment: Apparently OpenCV needs are different from what the imutils scripts does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685707/why-is-the-range-of-hue-0-180-in-opencv, I did my homework

Comment: @pippo1980 you can't have links in a piece of code. I see that you attempted this.

Comment: yep , was trying to sponsor the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685707/why-is-the-range-of-hue-0-180-in-opencv to have my "what about cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV vs cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL ???"?  comment solved